# PHP: Agrupar dados sem usar 'group_by'

Tags: php, query, loop, foreach, for

Alguém sabe como faço para agrupar dados sem usar *group_by* na consulta?

Preciso que a cada 10 resultados do laço (*foreach*), crie uma *div*, ou seja, 10 registros dentro de cada *div*, não me importa os valores.

```
<?php foreach($resultados->result() as $resultado){ ?>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i){ ?>
        <div>
    <?php } ?>
        <?=$resultado->id?>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i){ ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }// foreach ?>
```

Comment: Fiz um exemplo bem rápido: https://hastebin.com/awokiviyon.xml

Comment: DEU CERTO! Obrigado pela ajuda, a última <div> gerada fica vazia, mas tá servindo pra mim. Como faço pra dar uma nota pela ajuda?

Comment: @AndersonFelipe Para dar ponto, é a "triângulo" para cima. Para aceitar a resposta, marque o "V" que irá ficar verde. [IMAGEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer seria usando um contador auxiliar (`$c`) e módulo (`%)`.

Exemplo:

```
$c = 0;
foreach($resultados->result() as $resultado){

    if ($c % 10 == 0) echo  '<div>';
    echo $resultado->id;
    if ($c % 10 == 0) echo  '</div>';

    $c++;
}
```